# MySQL SELECT query from multiple tables at the same time

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I have schema like this in my database:
[image]

I want to display all recipes (with specific fields) which specific user (given with unique_id) has added to his favourites which are desscribed in table favourite (2 fields - user id and liked recipe). I have no idea how to to that.

f.e. If user likes 5 recipes, that information is included in the favourite table (his id and recipe he liked id). I want to display fields:

- recipe.`unique_id`,
- recipe.`title`,
- recipe.`img_tumbnail_link`,
- recipe.`add_date`,
- recipe.`kitchen_type`,
- recipe.`meal_type`,
- user.`name`,
- user.`surname`,
- COUNT(`like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) AS like_count

I've tried to do some query with this:

```
SELECT recipe.`unique_id`, recipe.`title`, recipe.`img_tumbnail_link`, recipe.`add_date`, recipe.`kitchen_type`, recipe.`meal_type`, user.`name`, user.`surname`, COUNT(`like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) AS like_count 
FROM `recipe` 
JOIN `favourite` ON (recipe.`unique_id` = `favourite`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) 
JOIN `like` ON (recipe.`unique_id` = `like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) 
JOIN `user` ON (recipe.`user_unique_id_fk` = user.`unique_id`)
WHERE favourite.`user_unique_id_fk` = '565096811c0b51.08471830' 
ORDER BY recipe.`add_date` DESC
```

From table like this:

[image]

with this query i receive only 1 row instead of 3 I should get for user with id: `565096811c0b51.08471830`. Any help? Thank you.

I've added recipes table and result:)

[image]

Here is my query result:

[image]

Here is all records (no duplicate): http://postimg.org/image/ejjemnozb/

Comment: Without seeing the data I'm finding it hard to walk through it. Can you put a sample up on sqlfiddle? Also, have you tried omitting the like components? Let's start with the easy parts first and gradually add more layers :)

Comment: @RichardSeviora I've added recipes table and my query result as u wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using join with **like** table as well which is having **only one row** thats why only one row is returned. You can calculate likes with **sub-query**. I have mentioned correct query below:

```
SELECT recipe.`unique_id`, recipe.`title`, recipe.`img_tumbnail_link`, recipe.`add_date`, recipe.`kitchen_type`, recipe.`meal_type`, user.`name`, user.`surname`, 
(SELECT count(*) from `like` WHERE recipe.`unique_id` = `like`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) AS like_count
FROM `recipe` 
JOIN `favourite` ON (recipe.`unique_id` = `favourite`.`recipe_unique_id_fk`) 
JOIN `user` ON (recipe.`user_unique_id_fk` = user.`unique_id`)
WHERE favourite.`user_unique_id_fk` = '565096811c0b51.08471830' 
ORDER BY recipe.`add_date` DESC
```

Comment: Look like it is fine. I just added records to like table instead of favourite table :D Thx now it works :) Can you also check this one: http://pastebin.com/LsRtwSeX (it selects top 5 recipes). It works fine but can it be made more simple?

Comment: This query is also having same error. Just use the query I mentioned above with one addition in end ` LIMIT 5`